# Prolog - showBoard of a game

Tags: prolog

I am trying to get a grid to show in prolog, rather than getting the `listing` of it.

Here is what I have so far

```
sB:-
    showBoard.

showBoard(Row) :-
    setof([Row,Col,Object,Visible],square(Row,Col,Object,Visible),RList),
    showRow(RList),
    writeln(''),
    NextRow is Row - 1,
    showBoard(NextRow).
```

This is something new that I am trying to test out to see if I can get this or not. Am I on the right track?

EDIT

For a task, we have to generate a grid through code,

Here is what I am trying to get....

I am using `square/3`, getting back square(x,y,object). But I hope to step it up to `square/4`, so I can bring in the visibility of the grid, meaning the robot can only see around him, one square left, right, up and down, until he finds his glasses.

---

```
== == == == == == == == == ==

|| x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x ||

|| x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x ||

|| x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x ||

|| x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x ||

|| x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x ||

|| x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x ||

|| x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x ||

== == == == == == == == == ==
```

Comment: Provide us with sample output you want.

Comment: Are you trying to get _this exact 8x7 grid_ or something which is inside such a grid?

Comment: And what is the format of the `square/4` facts in your database, if those contain the info that goes into the grid?

Comment: `square/3`. || and == is the walls of the grid. I have a robot, boiling pit, warm areas and glasses that also needs to be represented.

Comment: So can you tell us what `square/3` looks like maybe? Along with the rest of the relevant information?

Comment: `square/3` means square(x,y,object). But we could use square/4 because we have to set the visibility of the grid to the user, because he has to find his glasses before he finds the exit. with in the grid.

Comment: (add it to your question)

Comment: Question now updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to "scan" your board left-to-right, top-to-bottom (as this is how we output to a console), and see if there is anything to be shown for this particular square. Assuming that you are using `format` for writing (easier to control the formatting of the output), and assuming that you know in advance the size of your board, and your x and y coordinates start at the top left corner, you need to:

- for each row of the board:

  - for each position on the row

    - see if there is something to draw on that square, and draw it

Or, in code:

```
show_board(Rows, Cols) :-
    show_rows(1, Rows, Cols).

show_rows(R, Rows, Cols) :-
    (   R =< Rows
    ->  show_row(R, 1, Cols),
        R1 is R + 1,
        show_rows(R1, Rows, Cols)
    ;   true
    ).

show_row(R, C, Cols) :-
    (   C =< Cols
    ->  show_square(R, C) % or maybe show_square(C, R)?
        C1 is C + 1,
        show_row(R, C1, Cols)
    ;   true
    ).

% show_square should always succeed!
show_square(R, C) :-
    (   square(R, C, Obj /* additional arguments? */)
    ->  draw(Obj /* additional arguments */)
    ;   draw_not_visible
    ).
```

This could be a starting point. It could be done more "fancy" but this is a perfectly valid approach. Drawing an object depends on what your object is, and drawing the boundary around the grid is trivial.